# Question over limit of integrand for definite integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065070/limit-of-and-integral-depending-on-n/3066132#3066132) question, a question (for myself) arose about how limits of a definite integral are evaluated.

The limit integral takes the form:

\begin{equation}
 L = \lim_{n \rightarrow N} \int_{a}^{b} f_n(x)\:dx
\end{equation}

Now if $f_n(x)$ has a primitive $F_n(x)$ then:

\begin{equation}
 L = \lim_{n \rightarrow N} \int_{a}^{b} f_n(x)\:dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow N} \big[ F_n(a) - F_n(b) \big]
\end{equation}

My question is: Is the resultant limit expression equivalent to the integral with the limit applied to the integrand, i.e. is

\begin{equation}
 L = \lim_{n \rightarrow N} \int_{a}^{b} f_n(x)\:dx =  \int_{a}^{b} \lim_{n \rightarrow N} \:f_n(x)\:dx
\end{equation}

I've done some googling around and I haven't been able to find anything. Here impose that $f_n(x)$ is continuous over $[a,b]$.

Comment: Look up the Dominated Convergence Theorem.